# What videos should everybody watch?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Stanford University now has a [Youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/StanfordUniversity), with free access to HD video of full courses on everything from dynamical systems to quantum entanglement.  More conferences and workshops are videotaping their talks.  What are videos online that you think everyone should know about?

I'll seed this with a few answers to presentations that are mostly expository, but what I'm hoping might happen is that this community wiki could turn into a resource to share excellent presentations of new research, as well as a place to learn (or reinforce) background in an unfamiliar area.

Comment: Microsoft Research [also](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/microsoft+research) has a youtube channel. I also like [Dominic Verity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yilkBvVDB_w)'s talk on category theory for programmers. Asking everyone to watch _the same_ material seems like a bad idea because it will reduce diversity and increase groupthink.

Comment: Do we have any videos lectures related to basic approximation and randomized algorithms.

Comment: Can someone make an ongoing thread for the latest conference/workshop talks?  IPCO, ICALP, STOC, FOCS etc that are available online?

Answer (score 56):

Timothy Gowers has a [set of videos on Computational Complexity and Quantum Computation](http://www.sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/545358;jsessionid=53925A3FEE89D7505565619066A413C8) online.

Comment: I watched the first lecture in this series and find his explanation of Turing machines very awkward. Furthermore, he seems to suggest that circuits are somehow equal in power to TMs, which is not the case (unless there is more to them than he tells). He himself says he does not want to talk about "strange computation models" but rather about "familiar combinatorics" so I'd say these are rather maths, not TCS lectures.

Comment: combinatorics is also part of TCS.

Comment: Is TCS not part of mathematics, broadly defined for sure?

Comment: The sound quality is pathetic, amateur hour.

Answer (score 41):

[Richard Feynman's Messenger Lectures](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/tools/tuva/index.html#data=3|||) restored, with annotations, by Microsoft's Tuva Project.  Full disclosure: I've only watched two so far; they were awesome.  (Not really TCS, but I had to start with these.)

Comment: The Vega Science Trust (http://vega.org.uk/) also has some excellent Feynman talks on video, as well as talks from a bunch of other scientists.

Comment: I get told that my browser won't support the format (Silverlight).  Sigh.

Comment: @JimHefferon Does http://www.ubuntugeek.com/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html work for you?

Comment: While I admire what looks like a heroic effort to get it to go, no, I have never tried it. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

[Don Knuth's musings](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rNMsVRnSJ44WuwbminUqXX2) are great, always describing some amazing thing unknown to me before.

Comment: Can this videos be downloaded or do they have to be streamed using sliver light?

Comment: I feel like Knuth himself would disapprove of having them locked up in a proprietary format, and it sure is inconvenient for me.

Comment: @Max not anymore :-) (I updated the link).

Answer (score 27):

Institutes with online talk videos:

- [The Fields Institute at University of Toronto](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/audio/) (audio + slides)
- [The Institute for Advanced Studies](http://video.ias.edu/) in [School of Mathematics](http://video.ias.edu/sm) and [Computer Science and Discrete Mathematics](http://video.ias.edu/taxonomy/term/16)
- [The Institute for Advanced Studies/Princeton's Center for Computational Intractability](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/videos.html),
  e.g. [Barriers Workshops](http://intractability.princeton.edu/)
- [Isaac Newton Institute for Mathematical Sciences](http://www.newton.ac.uk/webseminars/)
- [Simons Institute for Theory of Computing](https://simons.berkeley.edu/videos)

Theory groups with online talk videos:

- [Theory Group in University of Chicago](http://cs.uchicago.edu/videos)

Also see this [blog post](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2010/09/cs-happenings.html) by Lance Fortnow.

Answer (score 25):

Stephen Boyd has his entire Stanford class on [Convex Optimization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McLq1hEq3UY) online.

Some interesting comments and asides, covers same material as in [his book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).

Answer (score 23):

Dan Spielman's [Nevanlinna Prize lecture](http://techtalks.tv/talks/nevanlinna-prize-talk-laplacian-gems-2/1335/) at Hyderabad 2010.  I got this link from a [blog post](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/icm2010-final-post/) by Timothy Gowers; the post contains several more video and text links to the 2010 ICM.

Answer (score 21):

There's a really interesting talk, given by Yuri Gurevich, on the Church-Turing thesis [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XfA5EhH7Bc).

Answer (score 20):

The video section of IAS is also a great source of online courses.  One of my favorite is:
[Ketan Mulmuley.  On P vs NP, Geometric Complexity Theory, and the Riemann Hypothesis.](http://video.ias.edu/csdm/pvsnp)

Answer (score 19):

FOCS (IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science)

- The FOCS 2010 videos are [now online](http://techtalks.tv/focs/2010/).  Glencora Borradille mentions her favorites in [this blog post](http://www.glencora.org/silent-glen-speaks/a-skulk-of-focs-talks/).

Comment: @Diego de Estrada  the site is down is there anywhere else I can find these videos?

Answer (score 16):

I do not know if this is a video lecture that everyone should watch, but I have decided on watching these to learn some Algebraic Topology. Seems pretty good to me so far.

[Algebraic Topology Lectures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdpbfOzkJzI&feature=related)

**EDIT** *(Added Later)*. Another nice set of video lectures

[Here is](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.889/fall11/lectures/) another wonderful set of lectures by Erik Demaine. The course is called [Planar Graph Algorithms and Beyond](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.889/fall11/) and is being taught by Erik Demaine, Shay Mozes, Christian Sommer and Siamak Tazari. They are also using some sections of Phil Kliens draft on Planar Graphs. I feel certain that it will make a great book after having seen the first two lectures.

Comment: The course of Demaine et al. is amazing!

Answer (score 15):

For people interested in quantum computation, the talks of QIP 2010 are available here:
http://www.qip2010.ethz.ch/programme

Answer (score 14):

This might seem pretty preliminary to most people here, but I have greatly benefited from these since I am essentially self-taught.
http://aduni.org/courses/theory/index.php?view=cw

Answer (score 13):

A completely hilarious video (and also very educational) is [Serre's now-famous video](http://en.sevenload.com/videos/h4ndeFL-Serre) on how to write mathematics badly.

Comment: «We are sorry but sevenload doesn't offer its service in your country». Sad…

Comment: @Artem: Maybe [this link](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xf88b5_jean-pierre-serre-writing-mathemati_tech) works for those outside the US? It works for me.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest the Channel 9 lectures: http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/c9+lectures

I like specially the lectures from Erik Meijer on functional programming.

Comment: Ralf Lämmel's [lectures](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/ralf-laemmel) are also nice. He also put videos for his [course on Programming Paradigms and Formal Semantics](http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~laemmel/paradigms1011/) online.

Answer (score 13):

I enjoyed Scott Aaronson's [lecture at Caltech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SczraSQE3MY) titled "Quantum Computing and the Limits of the Efficiently Computable." This lecture, which was in honor of Feynman, rehashes what's common knowledge to users of this site but in a very clear and funny way.

Answer (score 12):

[Quantiki](http://www.quantiki.org/) has a nice [video abstract site](http://www.quantiki.org/video_abstracts), where people are free to post a short video (3-6 minutes) describing their recent papers/preprints. As it is part of Quantiki, it largely focuses on quantum information/computation.

Answer (score 12):

STOC (ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing)

- The STOC 2011 videos are [now online](https://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1993636&preflayout=flat#prox) on ACM DL.

Comment: They're behind a paywall unfortunately...

Comment: This is probably an old news, but the videos are now available for free (but you have to register (again, for free)) http://t.co/LtTmi32

Comment: @Danu how do I access the videos? I only see articles no videos

Answer (score 12):

CCC (IEEE Conference on Computational Complexity)

- [The CCC 2010 videos](http://ccc2010.seas.harvard.edu/program.html)

Answer (score 11):

Erik Winfree describes DNA self-assembly and molecular programming at a [plenary talk](http://dmcc.acm.org/pres/?query=/dmcc///confdata/asplos2008/2008-03-03_09h06) at ASPLOS 2008. Probably the best rigorous introduction to the theory of self-assembly currently online.

Answer (score 11):

[Quantum Information, Computation and Complexity](http://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00092979/en/)

Comment: awesome! how was i waiting for watching video lectures on this topic...to think about watching lectures of Charles Bennet! A rare treat! Thanks again

Answer (score 11):

Erik Demaine has the video lectures up from his Fall 2010 course on geometric folding algorithms that follows the textbook he coauthored with Joseph O'Rourke:

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.849/fall10/lectures/

The lectures are great as you'd expect. But what really stands out to me is the production values: Each lecture's web page has embedded slides *and* lecture notes that play along in synchrony with the video. It uses high-definition HTML5 video with all the synchronization of slides and lecture notes done in JavaScript. Hopefully this will set a new standard of excellence.

Answer (score 9):

[MIT's Youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/MIT) might be useful as well.

Comment: The link is already mentioned in the question itself!

Comment: technically, only Stanford's youtube channel is mentioned

Answer (score 8):

Just found the following two websites. They were recommended by some folks, but I have not evaluated them yet:

- VideoLectures.net: http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/
- AacademicEarth.org: http://academicearth.org/subjects/computer-science/

Answer (score 7):

I'm late to answer,but find Cristian Calude's  [lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYjmiT422yQ)  on Incompleteness excellent.

Answer (score 7):

**CS Theory Toolkit by Prof. Ryan O'Donnell**.
Great for newbies, and includes interesting viewing angle on various topics:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLm3J0oaFux3ZYpFLwwrlv_EHH9wtH6pnX

Answer (score 6):

General audience talk by Michael Sipser about $\mathsf{P}$ vs. $\mathsf{NP}$:

Michael Sipser, ["Beyond Computation: The P vs NP Problem"](http://claymath.msri.org/sipser2006.mov), [CMI Public Lecture](http://www.claymath.org/public_lectures/), 2006.

Also available on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msp2y_Y5MLE).

Answer (score 5):

Videos from Banff events: [this one](http://www.birs.ca/events/2011/5-day-workshops/11w5117/videos) is from the ongoing workshop on approximations.

Answer (score 5):

These are a lectures series about Quantum Computation by professor David Deutsch

http://www.quiprocone.org/Protected/DD_lectures.htm

Another great series on Quantum Computation by Michael Nielsen aimed at the average Joe who wants to learn about Quantum Computation

https://m.youtube.com/#/playlist?gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google&list=PL1826E60FD05B44E4

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in concurrency theory, programming languages or interactive theorem proving, I warmly recommend the videos of the recent [Milner Symposium](http://events.inf.ed.ac.uk/Milner2012/videos.html). For example J. Parrow's talk *The pi-calculus: Origin and recent developments* tells the beautiful story of the early development of $\pi$-calculus, and B. Pierce's talk *Types à la Milner* is a lucid overview of work on types for process calculi.

Answer (score 5):

Following resources are very helpful: 
http://www.aduni.org/courses/ (Discrete Math, Algorithms, theory of computation and many others) and
http://erikdemaine.org/classes/ (I particularly like the algorithms on planar graphs lecture and advanced data structure lec here)

Answer (score 5):

[TCS+](https://sites.google.com/site/plustcs) (an online biweekly seminar series, using Google Hangouts as medium), has a [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/TCSplusSeminars), as well as a listing of previous lectures:

https://sites.google.com/site/plustcs/past-talks

(This listing also includes the slides of the talks).

The topics are quite diverse, and meant to cover all areas of TCS.

Answer (score 4):

General CS videos, found some good ones on here: http://lecturefox.com/computerscience/

Not restricted to Computing but good nonetheless: http://mitworld.mit.edu/

Comment: That's a great link for videos, however a better link would be to say which of these videos are worth the watch (or maybe they are all?)

Comment: I liked the Donald Knuth's lectures linked to on the lecturefox site (he created TeX amongst his other achievements) http://scpd.stanford.edu/knuth/index.jsp and on the mitworld site I liked I liked the "Computing for Everyone" lecture though I suspect they are all pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

Original - Structure and Implementaion of Computer Programs (SICP) by Hal Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman
http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/

If you have trouble with downloading all of the videos - you can dowload them from archive.org (on archive.org some links are not show up).
http://jcubic.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/abelson-sussman/

Answer (score 4):

[Videos](http://www.heidelberg-laureate-forum.org/event_2013/) of talks by several Abel, Fields and Turing laureates at [Heidelberg Laureate Forum](http://www.heidelberg-laureate-forum.org).

Answer (score 4):

The set of lectures by Ryan O'Donnell on *Analysis of Boolean Functions*, taught in 2012 at CMU, is really nice:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/aobf12/
The page includes the video recording of each lecture.

Comment: These are also excellent: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/complexity17/, and the series that starts with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxhpiYKFQd8

Answer (score 3):

Sipser gave a nice Clay Public Lecture on P vs. NP entitled "Beyond Computation"

http://www.claymath.org/public_lectures/sipser.php

and there is another one by Vijaya Ramachandra

http://claymath.msri.org/pversusnp.mov

Answer (score 2):

The archive of recorded seminars of the [Perimeter Institute](http://pirsa.org/) is both useful and entertaining.

[The Qubit Lab](http://www.youtube.com/user/qubitlab/feed) is a Youtube channel that explains advanced topics on  quantum information and computation at children level, but it's also very enjoyable if you are an adult.

Comment: This is also a nice basic Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_Riqjdh2oM

Answer (score 0):

The Richard Feynman YouTube video on magnets. Revealing how one of the greatest physicists of the 20th century cannot explain the force of magnetism (action at a distance) in terms of a simple mechanical procedure. "Yes Richard, I know there is a field there, but how does the field physically move the magnet "?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a TCS playlist, but it does have some interesting parts where they try to formalize some concepts. And I believe that it can be intercepted with natural computing, information theory and learning theory.

[Complexity Explorer: Origins of Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35vDDqjx2oE&list=PLEAYkSg4uSQ1h54OAaPBM-kYPtfGsgUL5)