# What podcast should everybody listen to?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

This list was inspired by the lists:

1. [What are the popular science books that inspire TCS?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18968/what-are-the-popular-science-books-that-inspire-tcs)
2. [What Books Should Everyone Read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read)
3. [What papers should everyone read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-papers-should-everyone-read)
4. [What videos should everybody watch?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/what-videos-should-everybody-watch)

I don't know if there are a lot of podcasts about Theoretical Computer Science, but if you have something that is relevant to that list it will be very good.

Answer (score 4):

Simons Institute for the Theory of Computing:
https://www.youtube.com/user/SimonsInstitute/featured

Institute for Advanced Study:
https://www.youtube.com/user/videosfromIAS/featured

Prinston TCS:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyGLYDvZ5BD5oYCIVv995HA/featured

Stanford Computer Science Theory:
https://www.youtube.com/user/StanfordCSTheory/featured

Innovations in theoretical computer science 2020:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBEzB8M6F5A&t=137s

DIMACS:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTKhyhoEPYyjU9PFW99A6Qw

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's an AI podcast but I love Lex Fridman's series:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrAXtmErZgOdP_8GztsuKi9nrraNbKKp4

Theoretical CS does pop up in at least a few episodes.

Answer (score 2):

I like very much the TCS+ series of online seminars:

https://sites.google.com/site/plustcs/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new quantum computing podcast, by Vincent Russo, William Slofstra, and Henry Yuen:

**Nonlocal: a quantum computing podcast** (https://nonlocal.libsyn.com/)

> This podcast takes you behind the scenes into the world of quantum computing research: through conversations with researchers, we explore the latest and most exciting ideas in the field. The podcast is aimed at anyone interested in quantum computing.