# Online TCS Seminars

Tags: soft-question

I want to have a list of online seminars that holds now.
So far I know only about TCS+(https://www.tcsplus.org/) seminars.
I would like to ask if there are other TCS seminars.

Comment: There is also a "live" list being maintained at cstheory-se.zulipchat.com.

Comment: Does it an empty list or I am looking at the wrong place?

Comment: Looking in the wrong place. I just sent you a message on Zulip.

Comment: See also mathseminars.org

Comment: The answers here may also apply:       https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46573/what-podcast-should-everybody-listen-to/46575#46575

Comment: The link in the question is dead unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still active as of November 2023:

- [TCS+](https://www.tcsplus.org/)
- [Online seminar on Algorithmic Aspects of Information Theory](https://www.lirmm.fr/%7Eromashchen/seminar-aait.html)
- Warwick [Online Complexity Seminar](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/%7Eigorcarb/complexity-meetings.html)
- Copenhagen/Lund [Mathematical Insights into Algorithms for Optimization (MIAO) Seminar](https://jakobnordstrom.github.io/miao-seminars/)
- [Online Logic Seminar](http://lagrange.math.siu.edu/calvert/OnlineLogicSeminar.html)
- [Aalto CS Theory Seminar](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Euittoj3/seminar.html)
- [COMSOC Video Seminar](https://sites.google.com/view/comsoc-seminar/)
- [Combinatorial Mathematics Society of Australasia Seminars](http://combinatorics-australasia.org/seminars.html)
- [Simons Institute YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/SimonsInstitute/)
- [DIMACS and CCICADA YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTKhyhoEPYyjU9PFW99A6Qw/)

The below seem to no longer be active, but their videos are still available and a great resource:

- [CMI Webinar series on Recent Connections to GCT and Progress in GCT](https://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Ekv/gctwebinar/gct-webinar-series.html)
- [Frontiers of Parametrized Complexity](https://frontpc.blogspot.com/2020/04/talks-schedule.html)

Comment: Another resource to find TCS seminars: https://researchseminars.org/ (you can filter by topic > Computer science > computer science theory)